# Are CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR and PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR the same in CMake?

Tags: cmake

[This page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables) contains a good summary of variables CMake already defines for us. I feel that some variables are the same. Take the example of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` for example. They are the same, referring to the folder where the top level CMakeLists.txt is defined. So my question is: are there subtle difference between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

There *is* a difference between these variables.  [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) does indeed refer to the folder where the top-level CMakeLists.txt is defined.  However, [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) refers to the folder of the CMakeLists.txt containing the most recent `project()` command.

For example, say you have a top-level project called `Outer` and this contains a subdirectory with its own project called `Inner`.  `Outer`'s CMakeLists.txt has:

```
project(Outer)
add_subdirectory(Inner)
```

and `Inner`'s:

```
project(Inner)
```

Then in both of these CMakeLists files, `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` will refer to `Outer`'s source dir.  But while `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` for `Outer` is also this same dir, this is not the case for `Inner`.  `Inner`'s `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is the subdirectory containing its CMakeLists.txt.

This difference applies to all `PROJECT_<var>` vs `CMAKE_<var>` variables.

Comment: Could you also add the difference with `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`?

Comment: So (in a single CMakeLists.txt project) it is a bad idea to put it in a subdirectory (say cmake)?

Comment: there is a need **to emphasize** that `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` requires the call of `project(aaa)` in order for `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` to have a value.

Answer (score 13):

Following Fraser's excellent answer.

[CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) is `the build directory being processed`.

Let's say you have a directory called `Inner1` containing a CMakeLists.txt file without calling `project` inside of it. Then `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is not set with `Inner1`'s dir path, but the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is set when being processed.

You may also find [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) interesting and the definition of [listfile](http://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary/listfile.html) useful.

Comment: This is an old comment now, but the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` link points to the older documentation for `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.