# How to load native library into native android code? (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android, c, android-studio, shared-libraries

I have a library in C called **mylib** in the folder
**jniLibs/your_architecture/mylib.so**

In Java, to load the library, you just have to type that code in your source:

```
static {
  System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}
```

But how can you load the library in a native C code (in Android Studio) ?
I add that the library don't use the JNI conventions, it's a normal shared library.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I also need to load a native library in C.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help someone, here how to load a library in native code c/c++ :

**1 -** to avoid `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:` add this to the build.gradle into `android` block :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

Assuming that your lib files are in

> src/main/jniLibs/{Architecture}/

( depending where is your `jniLibs` folder, in my case it is located at `app/src/main/` but the most time it is in `app/`)

---

**2 -** In your CMakeList, add you library as **SHARED** and **IMPORTED** by adding the following block :

```
add_library(mylib SHARED
            IMPORTED
            )
```

---

**3 -** Add target properties to locate you lib **mylib.so** by adding the following block :

```
set_target_properties( mylib PROPERTIES 
IMPORTED_LOCATION 
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/mylib.so
)
```

We back forward (/../) here because we concidere that CMakeLists.txt is in

> src/main/cpp/

Otherwise, the most time it is in `app/` folder, in this case, we don't need to back forward.

So we have to back to **main/** before going into **jniLibs/**

---

**4 -** Add you lib **mylib** to your target link libraries :

```
target_link_libraries(native-library-jni
                      ..
                      ..
                      mylib
                      ..
                      ..
                      )
```

---

**5 -** Finally, to call methods of your lib **mylib.so**, you have to create/copy-past the header containing these methods signatures and include it in your source file : `#include "mylib.h"`

You can now call your methods `[namespace::]method(args...)`

---

**Extra links :**

[PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html)

[CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html)

[Q : Are CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR and PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR the same in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028667/are-cmake-source-dir-and-project-source-dir-the-same-in-cmake?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)