# .so libraries on Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-sdk-2.3

I have Android SDK on my UBUNTU 16.4.

I need to add the below libraries to my android SDK

```
librt.so
libpthread.so
libcares.so
libcurl.so
libasound.so
libgcc_s.so
ld-linux-armhf.so
libvlc.so
libvlccore.so
libidn.so
```

how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the libraries files?

Comment: @E.Abdel not yet, But I searched and seems they are available to be downloaded. But is that enough?

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400454/use-so-shared-object-file-in-android-studio/51400846#51400846

Comment: @E.Abdel I am checking this link, but my problem is that , everyone is talking to solve it with android studio. but I have no clue how to handle it with android studio. I have installed it, but should I create a project? coy in the solutions it tells me too add the files in src for instance but how should I start with it?

Comment: Yes, to use your libs you have to create a project to handle the user side commands, your lib will be called from Java through JNI

Comment: @E.Abdel so Should I create an empty project in Android studio which will result in this architectture Manifest,java,res and then where should I cerate JNI folder and what should I load in it? just the .so files?