# cmake add_subdirectory fails on $(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)

Tags: cmake

I manage my dependencies using git submodules, and build my project using cmake. So far, this works rather well with all dependencies, except one (WebKit, I need it from source because I have to change some parts of it). The project uses "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR", ... all over the place, which results in the SOURCE_DIR of the parent project, thus, cmake fails in the configuration phase.

Is there a better way to include larger and more complex projects in a parent cmake project? I would like an approach that encapsulates the sub-project better, so that these issues cannot throw up any more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77668761/19739129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the use of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` in WebKit a bug. They should use `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`. See Fraser's answers for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32030551/2799037).

You might try to patch WebKit's code after checkout, prior to running CMake.
Additionally, you could open an issue to ask the developers to improve this. Or even better, create a pull request.

Comment: thanks. note that it is PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to include larger and more complex projects in a parent cmake project? I would like an approach that encapsulates the sub-project better, so that these issues cannot throw up any more.

Note: This question is a bit open ended so I'll ramble a bit here.

You can patch Webkit's code as pointed out above. And that is a good/valid suggestion. BUT it does make me think Webkit designed their project to be installed and consumed via a `package manager`. And they didn't consider the project to be consumed by `add_subdirectory`. Usually when I see `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` in popular projects this is the case.

That is a library choice. Not all libraries are designed to be consumed via `add_subdirectory`. In fact a fair amount of libraries are ONLY intended to be `installed` and then `found`. It's up to the library maintainers to decide what they want to support.

Personally I think the best way to consume large and complex projects is to use a package manager like `vcpkg`, `conan`, etc.

It makes dealing with larger dependencies like `boost` awesome. Which can be absolutely critical depending on your project.

NOTE: I have a slight bias toward vcpkg since I have contributed to it and got it working in a closed-source production environment that used boost, openssl, etc.

It will build your dependencies once. Then you just find them with `find_package`. Even better it provides binary caching. Which is fantastic for build performance when you have large dependencies (especially on Windows which doesn't have ccache).

What's nice about package managers is that generally speaking it makes you not have to care too much about the quality of the CMake code you are absorbing.

```
# vcpkg does this all under the hood for you
cd webkit
cmake -S . B build ...
cmake --build build ...
cmake --install build ...
```

A package manager handles all of this for you transparently.

Since you only care about installed files (Public headers, libraries, etc) then all you need is something like:

```
# NOTE: This is just an example. I'm not familiar with Webkit.

# NOTE: The library must add packaging support for this to work nicely!
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html
find_package(WebKit CONFIG)

# Ready to use libraries
target_link_libraries(foobar PRIVATE WebKit::foobar)
```

And you are ready to go.

What's even nicer about tools like vcpkg is it works well with projects that DON'T support CMake.

For example Make is still popular.

It will do the following behind the scenes

```
cd make_project
make ...
make install ...
```

And in that case you can just find the files you need via CMake's other `find` functionality.

```
find_file(...

find_library(...

etc.
```

`add_subdirectory` has it's pros (easy to use) and cons (difficult to deal with big projects)
`find_package` has it's pros (performance / cleaner CMake code) and cons (requires package manager, more initial setup, gotta learn another tool)

It depends on your project. But personally I've been loving using a package manager for build performance.

Note: You can also combine both approaches if you need to. Sky is the limit. Everyone has their own situation.

2nd Note: there are other solutions like FetchContent, and CPM. I have used them and still currently like vcpkg.

Comment: Thank you, but doing this is sadly out of the question, since I need to change some of WebKit's source anyway. So, installing it via the package manager would be more of a burden than a benefit.

Comment: vcpkg allow you to apply patches or even use custom ports. So you can can use a custom version of Webkit (IE your companies fork for example)

Comment: that is neat, good to know